# How to make python for loops faster

Tags: python, arrays, performance, for-loop, bigdata

I have a list of dictionaries, like this:

```
[{'user': '123456', 'db': 'db1', 'size': '8628'}
{'user': '123456', 'db': 'db1', 'size': '7168'}
{'user': '123456', 'db': 'db1', 'size': '38160'}
{'user': '222345', 'db': 'db3', 'size': '8628'}
{'user': '222345', 'db': 'db3', 'size': '8628'}
{'user': '222345', 'db': 'db5', 'size': '840'}
{'user': '34521', 'db': 'db6', 'size': '12288'}
{'user': '34521', 'db': 'db6', 'size': '476'}
{'user': '2345156', 'db': 'db7', 'size': '5120'}.....]
```

This list contains millions of entries. Each user can be found in multiple dbs, each user can have multiple entires in the same db. I want to sum up how much is the size occupied by each user, per each db. I don't want to use pandas.
At the moment I do it this way:

- I create 2 lists of unique users and unique dbs
- Use those lists to iterate through the big list and sum up where user and db are the same

```
result = []
for user in unique_users:
    for db in unique_dbs:
        total_size = 0
        for i in big_list:
            if (i['user'] == user and i['db'] == db):
                total_size += float(i['size'])
        if(total_size) > 0:
            row = {}
            row['user'] = user
            row['db'] = db
            row['size'] = total_size
            result.append(row)
```

The problem is that this triple for loop develops into something very large (hundreds of billions of iterations) which takes forever to sum up the result.
If the big_list is small, this works very well.

How should I approach this in order to keep it fast and simple?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not just create a map of user to list of dbs & their corresponding size?

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: Why don't you want to use pandas? It would make it trivial...

Comment: Is the data sorted by user and db?

Comment: "I want to sum up how much is the size occupied by each user, per each db." I don't quite follow. For the input shown here, what should the output be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main issue with the current approach: the **inefficient algorithm** and the **inefficient data structure**.

The first is that **the algorithm used is clearly inefficient** as it iterates many times over the big list. There is not need to iterate over the whole list to filter a unique user and db. You can iterate over the big list once and **aggregate data using a dictionary**. The key of the target dictionary is simply a `(user, db)` tuple. The value of the dictionary is `total_size`. Here is an untested example:

```py
# Aggregation part
# Note: a default dict can be used instead to make the code possibly simpler
aggregate_dict = dict()
for i in big_list:
    key = (i['user'], i['db'])
    value = float(i['size'])
    if key in aggregate_dict:
        aggregate_dict[key] += value
    else:
        aggregate_dict[key] = value

# Fast creation of `result`
result = []
for user in unique_users:
    for db in unique_dbs:
        total_size = aggregate_dict.get((user, key))
        if total_size is not None and total_size > 0:
            result.append({'user': user, 'db': db, 'size': total_size})
```

The other issue is the **inefficient data structure**: for each row, the keys are replicated while tuples can be used instead. In fact, a better data structure is to store a dictionary of `(column, items)` key-values where `items` is a list of items for the target column. This way of storing data is called a dataframe. This is roughly what Pandas uses internally (except it is a Numpy array which is even better as it is more compact and generally more efficient than a list for most operations). Using this data structure for both the input and the output should result in a significant **speed up** (if combined with Numpy) and a **lower memory footprint**.

Comment: Note it is roughly 8% faster to do your final results creation as a list comprehension, so `[{'user': user, 'db': db, 'size': total_size} for user in unique_users for db in unique_dbs if (total_size := aggregate_dict.get((user, key)))]`. Note that assuming sizes are positive, I believe `if total_size is not None and total_size > 0` can be simplified to `if total_size` since both a total size None and zero will evaluate to false. I will include the test code below for your reference. The timings are a bit erratic but the list comprehension is consistently faster.

Comment: @JohnM. Indeed for the comprehension list. For the sizes, they are certainly positive but maybe not strictly positive (ie. possibly null). Thank you for pointing this out and done the benchmark.

Comment: You welcome. You did all the hard work though. Null will still evaluate to false though, I believe.

Comment: Actually, I thought 8% wasn't right. The lookup key in `aggregate_dict.get((user, key))` should be `aggregate_dict.get((user, db))`. The bug meant the resultant list was empty as it was effectively searching for a tuple `(user, (key, value))`. Swapping to `db` makes the list comprehension 38% faster.

Answer (score 3):

Try mapping user to db to the total size in a dictionary. It will require additional memory but should be faster to access & requires only a single pass through the data:

```
user_to_db_to_size = {}
for entry in unique_users:
    user = entry['user']
    db = entry['db']
    size = int(entry['size'])
    if user not in user_to_db_to_size:
        user_to_db_to_size[user] = {}
    if db not in user_to_db_to_size[user]:
        user_to_db_to_size[user][db] = 0
    user_to_db_to_size[user][db] += size

print(user_to_db_to_size)
```

For your sample data it produces:

```
{'123456': {'db1': 53956}, '222345': {'db3': 17256, 'db5': 840}, '34521': {'db6': 12764}, '2345156': {'db7': 5120}}
```

And now you can access the total size per user/db with:

```
print(user_to_db_to_size['123456']['db1'])  # 53956
```

Comment: Just a note, caching the base dictionary lookup will give you a 5% speed improvements. I have included some benchmarks below.

Answer (score 3):

In summary, looking at the three suggested answers to this problem, the approach from rdas is probably the winner. With a couple of modifications, it is 57% faster than the solution for Jérôme, and 180 times faster than the original code. Сергей's solution was roughly 350 times slower on a much trimmed subset of the results (1000 entries); it also seemed to scale very badly and I did not have time to wait for results from the full dataset.

The timings are as follows:

| Method | Time | Relative |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Original | 102.83720700000413 | 180.4580695623077 |
| Jérôme | 0.8722491000080481 | 1.5306171118096032 |
| Jérôme (updated) | 0.9000219000154175 | 1.5793526426731528 |
| rdas | 0.6866130999987945 | 1.2048642527015463 |
| rdas (updated) | 0.6580462999991141 | 1.1547354157572032 |
| rdas with defaultdict | 0.5698675999883562 | 1.0 |

In Jérôme's answer, the final results calculation can be improved by swapping the final list construction to a list comprehension. Looking at the isolated list comprehension change, update code is roughly 38% faster. It is worth noting this isn't a major contributor to the overall time.

```
[{'user': user, 'db': db, 'size': total_size} for user in unique_users for db in unique_dbs if (total_size := aggregate_dict.get((user, db)))]
```

comparing before (Method1) and after (Method2) over a few iterations gives:

```
Method1: 6.447344800049905
Method2: 4.851344000024255
Method1: 6.546811900043394
Method2: 4.816081999975722
Method1: 6.863985500007402
Method2: 4.755402299982961
Method1: 6.8024070000392385
Method2: 4.738170499971602
Method1: 6.524162200046703
Method2: 4.755566900013946
```

The first update to rdas' answer was to avoid doing multiple dictionary lookups, by caching looking up the first dictionary:

```
if not (user_dict := user_to_db_to_size.get(user)):
    user_to_db_to_size[user] = { db: size }
elif not db in user_dict:
    user_dict[db] = size
else:
    user_dict[db] += size
```

this was subsequently improved again by swapping to `collections.defaultdict` which removes additional costly dictionary lookups:

```
user_to_db_to_size = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
for entry in big_list:
    user = entry['user']
    db = entry['db']
    size = int(entry['size'])
    user_to_db_to_size[user][db] += size
return user_to_db_to_size
```

This is the code used to run the benchmarks:

```
import random
import timeit
from collections import defaultdict

random.seed(1)

test_iterations = 100
big_list = [{'user': random.randint(0, 100), 'db': f'db{random.randint(1, 10)}', 'size': f'{random.randint(100, 90000)}' } for i in range(10000)]
unique_users = { i['user'] for i in big_list }
unique_dbs = { i['db'] for i in big_list }

def method0():
    result = []
    for user in unique_users:
        for db in unique_dbs:
            total_size = 0
            for i in big_list:
                if (i['user'] == user and i['db'] == db):
                    total_size += float(i['size'])
            if(total_size) > 0:
                row = {}
                row['user'] = user
                row['db'] = db
                row['size'] = total_size
                result.append(row)
    return result

def method1():
    aggregate_dict = dict()
    for i in big_list:
        key = (i['user'], i['db'])
        value = float(i['size'])
        if key in aggregate_dict:
            aggregate_dict[key] += value
        else:
            aggregate_dict[key] = value
    result = []
    for user in unique_users:
        for db in unique_dbs:
            total_size = aggregate_dict.get((user, db))
            if total_size is not None and total_size > 0:
                result.append({'user': user, 'db': db, 'size': total_size})
    return result

def method2():
    aggregate_dict = dict()
    for i in big_list:
        key = (i['user'], i['db'])
        value = float(i['size'])
        if key in aggregate_dict:
            aggregate_dict[key] += value
        else:
            aggregate_dict[key] = value
    return [{'user': user, 'db': db, 'size': total_size} for user in unique_users for db in unique_dbs if (total_size := aggregate_dict.get((user, db)))]

def method3():
    user_to_db_to_size = {}
    for entry in big_list:
        user = entry['user']
        db = entry['db']
        size = int(entry['size'])
        if user not in user_to_db_to_size:
            user_to_db_to_size[user] = {}
        if db not in user_to_db_to_size[user]:
            user_to_db_to_size[user][db] = 0
        user_to_db_to_size[user][db] += size
    return user_to_db_to_size

def method4():
    user_to_db_to_size = {}
    for entry in big_list:
        user = entry['user']
        db = entry['db']
        size = int(entry['size'])
        if not (user_dict := user_to_db_to_size.get(user)):
            user_to_db_to_size[user] = { db: size }
        elif not db in user_dict:
            user_dict[db] = size
        else:
            user_dict[db] += size
    return user_to_db_to_size

def method5():
    user_to_db_to_size = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    for entry in big_list:
        user = entry['user']
        db = entry['db']
        size = int(entry['size'])
        user_to_db_to_size[user][db] += size
    return user_to_db_to_size

assert (m0 := method0()) == method1()
print('Method1 OK')
assert m0 == method2()
print('Method2 OK')
assert all(v['size'] == method3()[v['user']][v['db']] for v in m0)
print('Method3 OK')
assert all(v['size'] == method4()[v['user']][v['db']] for v in m0)
print('Method4 OK')
assert all(v['size'] == method5()[v['user']][v['db']] for v in m0)
print('Method5 OK')

t0 = timeit.timeit(method0, number=test_iterations)
t1 = timeit.timeit(method1, number=test_iterations)
t2 = timeit.timeit(method2, number=test_iterations)
t3 = timeit.timeit(method3, number=test_iterations)
t4 = timeit.timeit(method4, number=test_iterations)
t5 = timeit.timeit(method5, number=test_iterations)
tmin = min((t0, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5))

print(f'| Method           | Time | Relative      |')
print(f'|------------------|----------------------|')
print(f'| Original         | {t0} | {t0 / tmin}   |')
print(f'| Jérôme           | {t1} | {t1 / tmin}   |')
print(f'| Jérôme (updated) | {t2} | {t2 / tmin}   |')
print(f'| rdas             | {t3} | {t3 / tmin}   |')
print(f'| rdas (updated)   | {t4} | {t4 / tmin}   |')
print(f'| defaultdict      | {t5} | {t5 / tmin}   |')
```

results in:

```
Method1 OK
Method2 OK
Method3 OK
Method4 OK
Method4 OK
| Method           | Time | Relative      |
|------------------|----------------------|
| Original         | 102.83720700000413 | 180.4580695623077   |
| Jérôme           | 0.8722491000080481 | 1.5306171118096032   |
| Jérôme (updated) | 0.9000219000154175 | 1.5793526426731528   |
| rdas             | 0.6866130999987945 | 1.2048642527015463   |
| rdas (updated)   | 0.6580462999991141 | 1.1547354157572032   |
| defaultdict      | 0.5698675999883562 | 1.0   |
```

Note Сергей's method is roughly equivalent to:

```
def c():
    tmp = Counter()
    for d in big_list:
        tmp = tmp + Counter(d)
    return tmp
```

so is effectively creating a new dictionary with every iteration in the loop. For each iteration in the loop the dictionary it creates will be bigger. I suspect this scales as `N ** 2` or worse.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Counter and make tuples of value pairs (user, db) as keys, then:

```
from collections import Counter

data = [{'user': '123456', 'db': 'db1', 'size': '8628'},
        {'user': '123456', 'db': 'db1', 'size': '7168'},
        {'user': '123456', 'db': 'db1', 'size': '38160'},
        {'user': '222345', 'db': 'db3', 'size': '8628'},
        {'user': '222345', 'db': 'db3', 'size': '8628'},
        {'user': '222345', 'db': 'db5', 'size': '840'},
        {'user': '34521', 'db': 'db6', 'size': '12288'},
        {'user': '34521', 'db': 'db6', 'size': '476'},
        {'user': '2345156', 'db': 'db7', 'size': '5120'}]

print(sum((Counter({(d['user'], d['db']): int(d['size'])}) for d in data), start=Counter()))

Counter({('123456', 'db1'): 53956, ('222345', 'db3'): 17256, ('34521', 'db6'): 12764, ('2345156', 'db7'): 5120, ('222345', 'db5'): 840})
```